# JavaScript add new input fields on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JavaScript Code that currently adds new textareas, inputs etc. inside a table and adds a unique number on each id/name

```
var i=1;
function addRow() {
          var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
          var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
          var iteration = lastRow - 1;
          var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

          var descriptionCell = row.insertCell(0);
          var elDescription = document.createElement('textarea');
          elDescription.type = 'textarea';
          elDescription.name = 'description' + i;
          elDescription.id = 'description' + i;
          elDescription.cols = 70;
          elDescription.rows = 2;
          descriptionCell.appendChild(elDescription);

          var unitpriceCell = row.insertCell(1);
          var elUnitPrice = document.createElement('input');
          elUnitPrice.type = 'text';
          elUnitPrice.name = 'unitprice' + i;
          elUnitPrice.id = 'unitprice' + i;
          elUnitPrice.size = 20;
          unitpriceCell.appendChild(elUnitPrice);

          i++;
          form1.number.value=i;
          //alert(i);

          document.getElementById("line").innerHTML = "whatever";
}
```

I have removed the table and now this is not working. How can I make the same thing work with text inputs and text areas without the table?

Comment: I generally recommend avoiding dynamic html like this. It tends to be hard to maintain. It's usually better to use a template based binding framework like KnockoutJS or similar

Comment: Within the `addRow` method you are using HTMLTable specific API calls (`row.insertCell(0)`). You will have to replace them with other DOM method calls, which will depend on the HTML structure you need to create. Can you share with us what the new HTML is for the form?

Comment: sure - check here http://pastebin.com/zbuKY3Be

Comment: You want a function to create, and append, `<input />` and `<textarea />` elements? Always both? Or should there be a means of appending one, or both? Should they have associated `<label>` elements also?

Comment: from my pasted example, i want to be able to click a button that will add a new fieldset (Line 2, Line 3 ++ etc) and inside the fieldset it will add a new description textarea and new price text input then each one it will add a unique number to the names of the inputs

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple approach to the problem:

```
function createFieldset(opts){
    // default settings:
    var s = {
        // finds the first form, could use "document.forms[0]" instead
        'appendTo' : document.querySelector('form'),
        // an array of elements you want to create:
        'create' : ['input', 'textarea'],
        // the element you want to wrap those elements with:
        'wrapper' : 'fieldset',
        // the className to apply to the wrapping-element:
        'wrapperClassName' : 'group',
        // the prefix of the 'legend' tag (if you want to use one):
        'legendPrefix' : 'Group '
    },
        // finding out where the count should start (by finding
        // the number of current wrapping elements), could use
        // 'document.getElementsByTagName(s.wrapper).length' or
        // 'document.getElementsByClassName(s.wrapperClassName).length':
        count = document.querySelectorAll(s.wrapper).length,
        // creating the wrapper element:
        container = document.createElement(s.wrapper),
        // finding out whether to use textContent or innerText:
        textProp = 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
        // caching temporary variables for later:
        created,
        tmp;

    // iterating through any user-set properties to update the
    // default settings:
    for (var prop in opts) {
        if (opts.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            s[prop] = opts[prop];
        }
    }

    // if we have a prefix of length > 0 once leading/trailing white-space
    // is removed, then:
    if (s.legendPrefix.trim().length > 0) {
        // create a 'legend' element:
        var legend = document.createElement('legend');
        // set the text of that legend element to 's.legendPrefix n'
        legend[textProp] = s.legendPrefix + count;
        // append that legend element to the container element:
        container.appendChild(legend);
    }

    // iterating over the array of elements to be created:
    for (var i = 0, len = s.create.length; i < len; i++){
        // caching the string of the element at position i in the array:
        tmp = s.create[i];
        // creating the element at that position:
        created = document.createElement(tmp);
        // setting the id, and name, to element-type + n:
        created.id = tmp + (count);
        created.name = tmp + (count);
        // appending the element to the wrapping element:
        container.appendChild(created);
    }

    // setting the className of the wrapping element:
    container.className = s.wrapperClassName;
    // inserting the element to the appendTo node, before its lastElementChild:
    s.appendTo.insertBefore(container, s.appendTo.lastElementChild);
}

createFieldset({
    'wrapperClassName' : 'first'
});

var button = document.querySelector('#addMore');
button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    createFieldset();
}, false);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mEFQG/4/).

References:

- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).
- [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/node.insertBefore).
- [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).